# How can I change the simulator user position in Objective-C MapKit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mapkit

I will the location update be hardcoded in simulator to my real position...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simulator running the 4.0 SDK and later uses built-in geolocation on its host platform to provide the actual current location of the computer it's running on. In other words, it doesn't just stupidly say it's at 1 Infinite Loop anymore, it tell you actually where it's at, provided your computer will do that.

So it could be as simple as upgrading your Xcode installation.